# Find files or symlinks to files with names matching a mask

Tags: find

I was running a search with `sudo find / -name gcc*`. It returns a bunch of directories while I only want files. But if I add `-type f` then it doesn't list symlinks, which I also want. How to filter out directories, but leave symlinks?

Additionally, I noticed that despite my `*` wildcard, it fails to list a file named `gcc-10`. Doesn't `find` support wildcards? Is there another utility that does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `man find`:

```
-type c
   File is of type c:
   [...]
   f      regular file
   [...]
   l      symbolic  link;  this is never true if the -L option or the -follow option is in effect, unless the symbolic link is broken.  If you want to search for symbolic links
          when -L is in effect, use -xtype.
```

In order for `find` to show you both symbolic  links aswell as files, use the parameter `-type f,l`.

Regarding wildcards: `find` does support wildcards. But because you are not quoting the expression (`-name gcc*` instead of `-name 'gcc*'`), your shell will expand `gcc*` to all files in your current working directory matching this wildcard expression before running `find`. (If this matched more than one file, you'd get a `find: paths must precede expression` error upon invocation, also explained in the `man`.)

So if you have a file called `gcc-xyz` in your current working directory, your shell will be running `find -name gcc-xyz`.

Comment: Ohh, I had no idea a `*` would be expanded even before invoking the command, I see! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Would be worth noting that the `-type f,l` where more than one type is given is specific to the GNU implementation of `find`. Portably, you'd need `'(' -type f -o -type l ')'`. In any case, that matches on symlinks whether or not they point to a regular file or other type of file (including directories).

Answer (score 2):

With the GNU implementation of `find`, you can use:

```
find / -name 'gcc*' -xtype f
```

For the  check for file `type` to be made after symlink resolution.

With `zsh` recursive globs, the same can be achieved with:

```
print -rC1 /**/gcc*(-.)
```

Where the `-` glob qualifier causes the following qualifiers (here `.` for the equivalent of `-type f`) to be applied after symlink resolution.

Instead of using `find`, if available, you could also use `locate` which is usually faster as it looks for files in a database that has already been built.

```
locate -b0 'gcc*' | find -files0-from - -prune -xtype f
```

With GNU `find` 4.9 or newer would get `locate` to list all the files whose `b`ase name starts with `gcc`, and `find` would filter the ones that can be determined to  be *regular files* after symlink resolution.

Or the same with `zsh` globs:

```
print -rC1 ${(0)^"$(locate -b0 'gcc*')"}(N-.)
```

Perl is also useful for that as its `-f` operator like `[`/`test`'s one tests for *regular* files after  symlink resolution by default, so you can do:

```
locate -b0 'gcc*' | perl -l -0ne 'print if -f'
```

Which would give you the result almost instantly without having to crawl the whole filesystem (though may miss some files that have been added after the last time to `locate` database was updated).